# debugging uncaught error in MATLAB while using unittest

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, debugging

I am fairly new in using MATLAB unittesting framework. I don't know how to debug uncaught errors there. I am looking for a way similar to using `dbstop if error` functionality in MATLAB scripts which would stop just at the line `c=(1:5)+randn(3)` in the script.

My question is how to do it in the following...

```
classdef sample_Test < matlab.unittest.TestCase

    methods(Test)
        function sampleAATest(testCase)

            a=1;
            b=3; 
            c=(1:5)+randn(3)
        end
    end
end
```

any help is appreciated as this feature seems to be quite useful in complicated tests

Comment: if an error is thrown somewhere else in other code you cannot intercept it at the line you want. But if you suspect this line has a potential for error you can [Set Conditional Breakpoints](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-236). They allow you to `pause` execution (still keeping the full stack and memory at this stage) if an expression of your choice is `true`.

Comment: thanks Hoki. The way I am using it seems not working for the example above. I set a breakpoint at line c and put the condition: b==3; here is what i put in the command line: close all;clc; clear classes; run(sample_Test). It actually doesn't stop

Comment: are you sure the code goes through there at all? If you place a hard breakpoint does it stops ? (and look at what does the workspace look like if it stops)

Comment: the code goes through since it is written in the unittest framework, however the test is unfinished. i guess the reason that I couldn't use breakpoints was because i used "clear classes" thanks to Andy for mentioning that

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't stop at the line in question, the [StopOnFailuresPlugin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.stoponfailuresplugin-class.html?refresh=true) can help you do this for other test failure types:

```
>> import matlab.unittest.*
>> import matlab.unittest.plugins.*
>>
>> suite = TestSuite.fromClass(?sample_Test)
>> runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput;
>> runner.addPlugin(StopOnFailuresPlugin);
>> runner.run(suite)
```

For uncaught exceptions it only catches the value after you have already exited the test method, which may not be as useful for you depending on your needs.

**EDIT**
For more recent releases you can do this pretty easily using the `'Debug'` option of runtests:

```
runtests('sample_Test', 'Debug', true)
```

**/EDIT**

Another way to do this for errors would be to issue

```
>> dbstop if all error
```

This will stop at the correct point and may work for this case but also stops at *all* caught errors. Sometimes this may be many errors and can take a while to get to the error you are interested in.

Finally, Hoki's suggestion in the comments is a good one. It is probably not working for you because `clear classes` also clears breakpoints.

Hope that helps!